# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pcId' of undefined

Tags: arrays

I'm new a JS and I'm receiving data on a JSON and later I must parse the info. I must fill one Array of arrays but I get this error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pcId' of undefined** when I try to catch the info.

```
function getDataBase(data){  
    console.log(data);
    var arrEmployee = [];
    var length = data.ttPerson.length;  
    console.log(data.ttPerson[0].pcId)
    for(var index = 0; index<= length; index++){
        console.log(data.ttPerson[index].pcId);
        var pcId = data.ttPerson[index].pcId;
        console.log(pcId);
    }; 
    var customerDataDB = [
        { id: arrEmployee[0], name: arrEmployee[0], picprofile:"", number:"345", subject:"Ingles", classroom: "23", build:"2", group:"17", sign:"", picture:"", ready:false, sent:false},     
        { id: arrEmployee[1], name: arrEmployee[1], picprofile:"", number:"345", subject:"Ingles", classroom: "23", build:"2", group:"17", sign:"", picture:"", ready:false, sent:false}
    ]; 
}
```

I wanna set the values of data in the arrEmployee or something to can build a array to pass to the DB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting that error, it's because you're trying to get the `pcId` property on a nonexistent (undefined) object. The likely problem areas that jumps out to me from your code are these:

`console.log(data.ttPerson[0].pcId)`

You're missing a semicolon there, but more importantly how can you be sure that the array `data.ttPerson` isn't size zero? If you try to call `data.ttPerson[0]` on an empty array you're working with an undefined object.

`for(var index = 0; index<= length; index++){`

Arrays use zero based numbering, so if you start at 0, you want to stop at `array.length - 1`. If you try to access `array[array.length]` you're outside of the range of the array and working with an undefined object. Your loop conditional should be either `index <= length - 1` or `index < length`.

Comment: I understand, the problem is the Object called data has actually two arrays inside. Are ttError and ttPerson and the console output shows me the content of the variable every time is called the console.log and below is showed the error. I already have methods for ensure the Object contains data (: